# What would be the official colors for Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sign in buttons?

Tags: discussion, design

I have a CSS library for social buttons ([lipis/bootstrap-social](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/)) and I'm thinking of adding the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange to the collection.

What would be the single HEX value for each of the buttons if it was used as the background of the button?

[image: social sign in buttons]

Here is the example [jsbin.com/numaki](http://jsbin.com/numaki/18/edit?css,output) if you want to play around, where the colors were taken from a [pull request](https://github.com/lipis/bootstrap-social/pull/28) with values `#4679b7` and `#d38b23`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but there are no such colours as sign-in uses 3rd party logos on a white/grey BG colour (like Google/Facebook) or the Stack Exchange login is the SE logo on a white/grey BG colour.